# Why JPA deletes a first element on Many to one relationship?

Tags: jpa, mariadb

After update a record on mariadb jpa deletes the first element of a onetomany manytoone relationship.

I have this entities (Getters and Setter are omitted)

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "regulation")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Regulation {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID_REGULATION")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "token")
  private String token;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id_transmitter")
  private Long transmitter;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id_document")
  private Long document;
  @Column(name = "is_valid", nullable = false)
  private boolean isValid = true;


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Regulation [id=" + id + ", token=" + token + ", name=" + name + ", transmitter="
        + transmitter + ", document=" + document + ", isValid=" + isValid + ", entity=" + entity
        + ", sectorIndustry=" + sectorIndustry + ", department=" + department + "]";
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "regulationEntity", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<RegulationEntity> entity;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "regulationDepartment", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<RegulationDepartment> department;
}

@Entity
@Table( name= "regulation_entity")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class RegulationEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID_REGULATION_ENTITY")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "RegulationEntity [id=" + id + ", entity=" + entity + "]";
  }
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id_entity")
  private Long entity;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID_REGULATION", referencedColumnName="ID_REGULATION")
  private Regulation regulationEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table( name= "regulation_department")
public class RegulationDepartment {

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "RegulationDepartment [id=" + id + ", department=" + department + "]";
  }
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID_REGULATION_DEPARTMENT")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id_department")
  private Long department;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID_REGULATION", referencedColumnName="ID_REGULATION")
  private Regulation regulationDepartment;
}
```

And this class

```
public class RegulationVO {

  private Long id;
  private String token;
  private String name;
  private Long transmitter;
  private Long document;
  private boolean isValid;
  private List<Long> entity;
  private List<Long> department;
}
```

And Using CrudRepository

```
public interface RegulationRepository extends CrudRepository<Regulation, Long>{ 
}
```

An update process

```
@Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseBean> updateRegulation(RegulationVO regulationVO){
    ResponseBean response = new ResponseBean();
    try {
      Regulation regulation = this.getRegulationUpdated(regulationVO);
      Regulation saved = this.regulationRepository.save(regulation);
      log.info(saved.toString());
      response.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch(Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      response.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, response.getHttpStatus());
  }

  public Regulation getRegulationUpdated(RegulationVO regulationVO) {
    Regulation regulation = this.regulationRepository.findById(regulationVO.getId()).get();
    regulation.setToken(regulationVO.getToken());
    regulation.setName(regulationVO.getName());
    regulation.setTransmitter(regulationVO.getTransmitter());
    regulation.setDocument(regulationVO.getDocument());

    List<RegulationEntity> listaEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Long idEntity : regulationVO.getEntity()) {
      log.info(idEntity.toString());
      RegulationEntity regulationEntity = new RegulationEntity();
      regulationEntity.setEntity(idEntity);
      regulationEntity.setRegulationEntity(regulation);
      listaEntities.add(regulationEntity);
    }
    regulation.getEntity().clear();
    regulation.getEntity().addAll(listaEntities);

    List<RegulationDepartment> listaDepartments = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Long idDepartment : regulationVO.getDepartment()) {
      log.info(idDepartment.toString());
      RegulationDepartment regulationDepartment = new RegulationDepartment();
      regulationDepartment.setDepartment(idDepartment);
      regulationDepartment.setRegulationDepartment(regulation);
      listaDepartments.add(regulationDepartment);

    }
    regulation.getDepartment().clear();
    regulation.getDepartment().addAll(listaDepartments);

    return regulation;
  }
```

But after save the updated object JPA deletes the first record of my RegulationDepartment List.

Output after save

```
Regulation [id=29, token=002AV01, name=Regulation, transmitter=1, document=1, isValid=true, entity=[RegulationEntity [id=179, entity=5], RegulationEntity [id=180, entity=8], RegulationEntity [id=181, entity=9]],  department=[RegulationDepartment [id=165, department=1], RegulationDepartment [id=166, department=2], RegulationDepartment [id=167, department=3]]]
```

Log JPA

```
2019-07-19 08:49:01.688 DEBUG 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from regulation_entity where id_regulation_entity=?
2019-07-19 08:49:01.688 TRACE 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [177]
2019-07-19 08:49:01.688 DEBUG 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from regulation_department where id_regulation_department=?
2019-07-19 08:49:01.688 TRACE 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [165]
2019-07-19 08:49:01.703 DEBUG 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from regulation_entity where id_regulation_entity=?
2019-07-19 08:49:01.703 TRACE 5724 --- [nio-8093-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [178]
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

For the list RegulationEntity that's no happening and is the same type of relationship.

Comment: Because you you remove all existing persistent instances from the collection??`regulation.getDepartment().clear();`

Comment: I do the same with regulation.getEntity().clear(); and for this list and it persists correctly, deletes the previous records and insert the new ones. But with the RegulationDepartment list deletes the previous but always deletes the first of the new ones after the insert.